# Stubbing api call in rails controller with RSPEC and ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rspec, rspec-rails

I have the following rails controller

```
class FoodsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_food, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /foods/1
  def show
   
    #render json: @food
    render json: 
    {
      "barcode": @food.barcode,
      "product": @food.product
    }
  
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_food
      #@food = Food.find(params[:id])
      
      code = params[:id]
      product = Openfoodfacts::Product.get(code, locale: 'fr')
      @food = Food.create_with(product: product.product_name).find_or_create_by(barcode: code)
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def food_params
      params.require(:food).permit(:barcode, :product)
    end
end
```

I have the following rspec test

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe FoodsController, type: :request do
  include_context 'openfood_context'

  let(:headers) { { Authorization: "Token #{TokenAuth::API_TOKEN}" } }
  let(:response_body) { JSON.parse(response.body) }
  let(:given_product) { response_body['product'] }
  let(:given_barcode) { response_body['barcode'] }

 
  before do
    get food_path(id: barcode), headers: headers
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    
  end

  it 'returns the product name' do
    
    expect(given_product).to eq product
  end

  it 'returns the barcode' do
    expect(given_barcode).to eq barcode
  end
end
```

The pages works and when I hit the foods/099482476885 route I get the output in this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkNiR.png).but when I run the spec I get the error below

```
1) FoodsController returns the product name
     Failure/Error: product = Openfoodfacts::Product.get(code, locale: 'fr')
     
     WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
       Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/produit/049000061017.json with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}
     
       You can stub this request with the following snippet:
     
       stub_request(:get, "https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/produit/049000061017.json").
         with(
           headers: {
          'Accept'=>'*/*',
          'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3',
          'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'
           }).
         to_return(status: 200, body: "", headers: {})
     
       ============================================================
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/webmock-3.13.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:114:in `request'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/webmock-3.13.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:123:in `start_without_connect'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/webmock-3.13.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:150:in `start'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/openfoodfacts-0.6.0/lib/openfoodfacts/product.rb:25:in `get'
     # ./app/controllers/foods_controller.rb:23:in `set_food'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:29:in `request'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test.rb:266:in `process_request'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test.rb:119:in `request'
     # ./spec/requests/foods_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/webmock-3.13.0/lib/webmock/rspec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I then try to add the following stub to spec/spec_helper.rb but get an error similar to the one in the picture. How do I solve this spec issue?

```
 config.before(:each) do
    stub_request(:get, /api.openfoodfacts.org/).
      with(headers: {
        'Accept'=>'*/*', 
        'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3',
        'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
      to_return(status: 200, body: "stubbed response", headers: {})
  end
```

Comment: One apparent problem is that the host in your stub's regular expression is `api.openfoodfacts.org`, but in the error message the GET appears to hit `fr.openfoodfacts.org`, so your stub is not matching. If you still have problems, try removing the headers from the stub to ensure that things are basically working first.

Comment: Also, please don't post screenshots of error/stack traces. Just copy the (relevant) text into your question. It would have been 10x easier to spot your problem had the error text not been a separate image.

Comment: When I change the host in the sub from api.openfoodfacts.org to fr.openfoodfacts.org I get ```  FoodsController returns the product name
     Failure/Error: product = Openfoodfacts::Product.get(code, locale: 'fr')
     
     JSON::ParserError:
       767: unexpected token at ''
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/openfoodfacts-0.6.0/lib/openfoodfacts/product.rb:26:in `get'
     # ./app/controllers/foods_controller.rb:23:in `set_food'  
     # /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in 
    ```

Comment: You're getting a JSON parse error, so I reckon that your original issue is fixed and possibly the problem is whatever JSON your stub is returning ("stubbed body"?) is causing your `Openfoodfacts` thing indigestion. If you make sure the stubbed a valid example response, it will likely get better.

Comment: There's a chance the service is called twice. Possibly you need to mock both of the enpoint. Pay attention what changes when you mock one. (Maybe api.foodfacts returns a 301 redirect to fr.foodfacts?)

Answer (score 0):

You are stubbing a request to `api.openfoodfacts.org` but you shared an error complaining about an outgoing request to `fr.openfoodfacts.org`.

Webmock will block all external requests in your specs (this is by design), so when you stub request to `foo`, pay extra attention if the error message changed to `Unregistered request: bar`. You would need to stub all of them,

Or [mock](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs) the `Openfoodfacts::Product` itself:

```rb
allow(Openfoodfacts::Product).to receive(:get).and_return(...)
```

(this will de-factor disable "normal" behavior of this class, and any call would just return what you told it to return.

The third option could be to use [VCR gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) which can record requests and responses and then mocks them for you.

Each solution has its pros and cons, which (I think) go outside of the scope of this question.